# How do I add the branch creator to `git checkout` branch completion in zsh?

Tags: git, zsh, zsh-completion

When you want to check out a git branch you can type `git checkout`TAB to list the available branches:

```
$ git checkout feature-
feature-1 feature-2
```

How can I add additional info such as branch creator and updated ago to the list of autocompleted branches?

```
$ git checkout <TAB>
develop by Full Name 2 hours ago
staging by Full Name 1 day ago
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to override the [zsh completion commands](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh) provided by git.